# Referencing a Document Class from a child MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, class, document

I have a document class with a child MovieClip on the stage. I have the clip already on the stage because it's part of an complex layout provided by the designer and it seems easier to leave it on the stage than to use addChild (since I would have to add about 60 objects).

What is the best way to reference the document class from inside the child MovieClip class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MovieClip(root)` to access your document class, provided that the swf is not being loaded into another swf.

So if you have on your documentclass some function myFunction(), in your child movieclip you can call `MovieClip(root).myFunction()`